# Move "active" cell in Googles Sheet macro language

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to write a function that pulls the nth (in example 4th) column of data from a sheet starting at a certain row/column, whose address is defined as a variable. I tried using offset but the .getrange() to move the "active" cell to the nth position and make that cell the active cell but macro aborts. Has anyone done this? Due to nature of data, it is important that I move the "active" cell n columns. Subset of code below:

```
function PullSelectedData() {

//

var GeneralDataFirstLocation = "D4";   //data starting point cell D4

var ColumnsBetweenSeries = 4;          //want data from each of the 4 columns (e.g.; D4, H4, L4, P4....)

var ReturnedValue = 0;

//

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var BondCheckSS = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("BONDCHECKSHEET");

//

  for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

      BondCheckSS.getRange(GeneralDataFirstLocation).Offset(0, ColumnsBetweenSeries * i).activate();

      ReturnValue = getActiveCell().getValue();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why it crashed

- The first issue is that `Offset` is not a function, so it should be [`offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)), though your arguments for the function are correct, so that issue is resolved.
- The next issue is that `getActiveCell` is not a function on its own, it must be called on the sheet. For example, [`MySheet.getActiveCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell)
- A third issue that doesn't cause your code to crash, but allows you to use the `ColumnsBetweenSeries` variable, is changing your loop to `for (var i = 0; i < ColumnsBetweenSeries; i++) {`

#### Unwanted behavior

At this point, your code now runs fine, it no longer crashes, but there is still an issue, it doesn't quite do what you want it to do. Here is what it looks like now

```js
function PullSelectedData() {
  var GeneralDataFirstLocation = "D4"; //data starting point cell D4
  var ColumnsBetweenSeries = 4;        //want data from each of the 4 columns (D4, H4, L4, P4)
  var ReturnedValue = 0;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var BondCheckSS = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("BONDCHECKSHEET");

  for (var i = 0; i < ColumnsBetweenSeries; i++) {
      BondCheckSS.getRange(GeneralDataFirstLocation).offset(0, ColumnsBetweenSeries * i).activate();
      ReturnedValue = BondCheckSS.getActiveCell().getValue();
  }
}
```

The main problem is that `ReturnedValue` gets overwritten every iteration of the loop. So we need to either add it to a total every iteration, or we can put them all in a list with which we can do further processing afterwards.

If we wish to add each cell's value to a total, then the line where you set `ReturnedValue` in the loop becomes the following

`ReturnedValue += BondCheckSS.getActiveCell().getValue();`

If we want to put it all in a list, we can add each of the elements to a list using the append function, `MyList.append(valueToAppend)`, in which case, declaring `ReturnedValue` becomes the following:

`var ReturnedValue = [];`

and inside the loop, setting `ReturnedValue` becomes the following, which adds each value to the end of the list

`ReturnedValue.append(BondCheckSS.getActiveCell().getValue());`

Sum example

```js
function PullSelectedData() {
  var GeneralDataFirstLocation = "D4"; //data starting point cell D4
  var ColumnsBetweenSeries = 4;        //want data from each of the 4 columns (D4, H4, L4, P4)
  var ReturnedValue = 0;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var BondCheckSS = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("BONDCHECKSHEET");

  for (var i = 0; i < ColumnsBetweenSeries; i++) {
      BondCheckSS.getRange(GeneralDataFirstLocation).offset(0, ColumnsBetweenSeries * i).activate();
      ReturnedValue += BondCheckSS.getActiveCell().getValue(); // Notice the change from = to +=
  }
}
```

List example

```js
function PullSelectedData() {
  var GeneralDataFirstLocation = "D4"; //data starting point cell D4
  var ColumnsBetweenSeries = 4;        //want data from each of the 4 columns (D4, H4, L4, P4)
  var ReturnedValue = []; // Notice change from 0 to []

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var BondCheckSS = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("BONDCHECKSHEET");

  for (var i = 0; i < ColumnsBetweenSeries; i++) {
      BondCheckSS.getRange(GeneralDataFirstLocation).offset(0, ColumnsBetweenSeries * i).activate();
      ReturnedValue.append( BondCheckSS.getActiveCell().getValue() ); // We now append each value to the list instead of overwriting it each time
  }
} // ReturnedValue is now filled with the values of D4, H4, L4 and P4, Ex: [10, 20, 30, 40]
```